# react-native-firebase/storage - upload image to firebase storage error "_storage.default.storage is not a function"

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have installed @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/storage
Below is my package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^6.0.4",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
```

...this is where I require @react-native-firebase/storage

```
import rnFb from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
```

..and this is the function I am calling to upload the image:

```
  uploadImage = localUri =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const localUri2 = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? localUri.replace('file://', '') : localUri;
      const fbUri = Firebase.storage().ref();

      rnFb.storage().ref(localUri2).putFile(fbUri)
        .then(() => { resolve(); })
        .catch((e) => { reject(e); }); 
    });
```

Error Im getting is:

```
TypeError: _storage.default.storage is not a function
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

...
storage().ref(localUri2)
...
```

or

```
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

...
firebase.storage().ref(localUri2)
...
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for code.....now have a new error:  "Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:
1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
"

Comment: It seems you did not link the libs properly. If you use react native version >= 0.60.0, it will be auto linked. Otherwise, you have to follow this instruction https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/app/android and https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/storage/android